# Full node syncing/synced?

Tags: iri-node, syncing

I find the logs of the full node kind of confusing.

How to know when my full node is syncing or if it is fully synced?

Comment: What do you even consider synched?

Comment: Probably whether the latest milestone issued by the Coordinator has been (1) seen, and is (2) solid. :)

Answer (score 4):

When retrieving node info from your node, you will see `latestMilestone` as well as `latestSolidSubtangleMilestone` (this will also appear in the status bar of the wallet if you use it to connect to your node).

If the values are the same as the majority of nodes listed on https://iotanode.host/ (or another site that fetches and aggregates milestones of public wallet nodes), your node is synced.

When only `latestMilestone` is the same, but not `latestSolidSubtangleMilestone`, your node has seen the latest milestone itself, but not all the confirmed transactions connected to it, so your node is *not* fully synced. When even `latestMilestone` is off, you are probably offline or very badly connected (or connected to badly connected neighbors only, or your node has crashed), as milestones should be broadcast with priority through the network.

Comment: What to do when my latestMilestone is same but latestSolidSubtangleMilestone is stuck to a fix previous number?

Comment: @AgustinTena check your neighbours if they have it, if not find better neighbours. If yes, it should be only a matter of time until you get it too (maybe restart your node?)

Comment: My neighbors are sync. Always that I restart the node the problem gets fixed, but it ends up getting stuck again. Also the latestMilestone gets stuck.

Comment: do you have `OutOfMemoryError` in your logs? If yes, either reduce the native memory of your Java process with `-Xmx` or increase the RAM available on your node. If not, probably a(nother) bug somewhere in the node :(

Comment: Is http://iota.dance/nodes some kind of central source of truth? Or how is the "majority" calculated? (btw: list is offline, 404)

Comment: @MatthiasLohr It used to query all nodes available in the official light wallet's dropdown and showed their milestones. If most of these nodes (i. e. the majority of them) shows some milestone, it can be quite sure that it is truth (as no light wallet user would have seen anything else). I updated the link to one that is not broken and added a comment to what it is doing, for next time the link is down).